# Extending Azure multistage yaml pipelines logs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to log completion of each stage of multi  stage yaml pipelines with some custom details.
How can i add custom details to https://dev.azure.com//_settings/audit logs.
Is there a way to persist this information in sqldb or any other persistant storage option.
How can i subscribe to the these log events.

Comment: may I know how's the status of this? Does below work around is suitable for you to achieve what you want?

Comment: We want to publish some custom pipeline variables to this audit database. Since customizing audit data is not available, we are going make REST call to PaaS api and update what we need in an IaaS sql db instance using REST API call task.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i add custom details to
>   https://dev.azure.com//_settings/audit logs.

I'm afraid this does not available for you to achieve.

Because the sentence format of `details` is defined and fixed by our backend class. Once the corresponding action occurred, beside the action class, the event method will also be called to generate and record the log into audit page. These are all finished by backend. And we haven't expose this operation permission to users until now.

But based on my own, this is a good idea that we may consider to expand. Because **Customized details** can make the `details` more readable for the company. You can raise your idea [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), vote and comment it. Our corresponding Product Group review these suggestion regularly, and consider to take into our develop roadmap depend on its priority(*votes*).

---

> How can i subscribe to the these log events.

There has one important thing that I need let you know, the `audit log` only keep for 90 days. And it will be cleared after 90 days, **including our backend database**. The nutshell is, if you want the audit logs which more than 90 days, we also have no idea to help on restore that.

So I suggest you can configure one **scheduled** pipeline with `Powershell` task.

In this powershell task, run this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/audit%20log/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get and then store it with any file type you want, e.g `.csv`, `.json` and etc.

For the **schedule value**, you can set it as any time period you like. Just less than 90 days, so that it do not make you lose any audit event log.

---

> Is there a way to persist this information in sqldb or any other
>   persistant storage option.

If you can use a different database, I'd better suggest you consider to using a document storage solution such as `CouchDB`, `DynamoDB` or `MongoDB`.

Depend on your actual used, you can make use of `Command line task` with self-agent, to execute corresponding storing commands.

For sample, what I used is MongoDB and I can run below commands to store the JSON file that api generated previously:

```
C:\>mongodb\bin\mongoimport --jsonArray -d mer -c docs --file audit20191231.json
```